# How to plot a column chart rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

In the code below, I would like to increment variable a, then at the end, I would like to plot the graph by using the variable `a`.

```
<% a = 0 %>
<% something.each do |some|%>
  <% a = a + 1%>
<% end %>
<%= column_chart [{name: "column 1", data: "a"} ]%>
```

When I do it now, the graph does not plot anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create the chart data. Then you need to pass this data to column_chart as an argument.
The following example, `a` is actually the index of the somethings collection.

```
data = []
somethings.each_with_index do |something, a|
  data << [someting.name, a]
end

# data => [['name1', 0], ['name2', 1], ['name3', 2], ..]

column_chart data
```

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as the correct answer :)